# SQL Query Compare Columns of different tables even when NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, rdbms

I am by no means strong with SQL syntax and am teaching myself as I go.  I am struggling with a SQL query that I am using to compare prices (current and past) of inventory items based off of a finished goods parent item.

The inventory items are either purchased or created in-house. I have 3 tables to compare: a table `[FinishedGood]` that contains the parent item and the components it requires, a table `[Inventory]` that contains all inventory items (both purchased and created in-house), and a table `[Purchased]` that holds only purchased items. The latter two hold pricing values.

As an example, let's say I am making a YO-YO. I make the body of the yo-yo but buy the string and shaft. The body will be a static expense found in the 2nd table. However, the purchased goods can fluctuate in price (the 2nd table contains the most recent price for all goods). The 3rd table can be used to see the price in the last 3 months for only purchased goods.

Now the problem I am seeing is when I compare table 3 (only purchased goods prices) my query results hide the in-house created items (I've attached a picture of what I am wanting to achieve) And below is a sample of what I've written so far.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    vdvFinishedGood.StepID AS [Step],
    vdvFinishedGood.ComponentID AS [Component],
    vdvInventory.LastUnitCost AS [Current Cost],
    (vdvPurchased.Cost) AS [Purchased Cost]
FROM 
    vdvFinishedGood
JOIN 
    vdvInventory ON vdvInventory.ComponentID = vdvFinishedGood.ComponentID
JOIN
    vdvPurchased ON vdvPurchased.ComponentID = vdvFinishedGood.ComponentID
WHERE 
    vdvFinishedGood.ItemId = 'YOYO'
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bF2MZ.jpg]

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8638ad/1/0

Comment: You should try a `RIGHT JOIN` on vdvPurchased.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: To make answering the question as easy as possible, you should add a tag for the database product and create a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) if possible.

Comment: I tried this and get the same results. As a test I did comment out the select and join for the vdvPurchased and I get the correct components. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Question can not be answered without following @Matthias indications. I will vote to close it until further update

Comment: Looks to me like you need to use a left join instead of an inner join. But without some data and desired output this is impossible to answer.

Comment: please see the attached sqlfiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8638ad/1/0

Comment: The data is rather strange as `vdvPurchased` does not contain a date column. What would you do if it had multiple results per `ComponentID` how would you know which row to pick?

Comment: I'm currently going to use the MAX value but in the future I would like to investigate the usage of a case statement. Where it would look for dates (the real table does have this) for the last 3 months, if there has not been a transaction in that time frame then it will be set to the inventory price

Comment: LEFT JOIN took care of my problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of a `JOIN` when joining the table `Purchased`. I modified your fiddle as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    FinishedGood.StepID AS [Step],
    FinishedGood.ComponentID AS [Component],
    Inventory.LastUnitCost AS [Current Cost],
    Purchased.Cost AS [Purchased Cost]

FROM FinishedGood
JOIN Inventory ON Inventory.ComponentID = FinishedGood.ComponentID
LEFT JOIN Purchased ON Purchased.ComponentID = FinishedGood.ComponentID

WHERE FinishedGood.ItemId = 'YOYO'

ORDER BY [Step]
```

Result:

```
 Step  Component  Current Cost  Purchased Cost 
 ----- ---------- ------------- -------------- 
 001   Body       1.00          (null)         
 002   String     0.25          0.55           
 003   Shaft      1.15          1.15
```

See modified fiddle at [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8638ad/7).